# EXM issue : Failed to send '579dc3d4-4aee-4308-af71-f5202483356f' (messageid) to 'website PII removed'

Tags: exm

We have a setup where we send the reports to customer using EXM in sitecore 9.

I keep getting exception in EXM log where its unable to deliver all mails to recipients.
`ERROR [AutomatedMessageHandler] Failed to send '579dc3d4-4aee-4308-af71-f5202483356f' to 'website PII removed'`

Result:          ABORTED
  Message Id:      {579DC3D4-4AEE-4308-AF71-F5202483356F}
  Message Path:    project specific
  Recipients Processed:2394
  Message Total Sent Recipients:2207
  Message Total Failed Recipients:44

Detail Trace

```
Failed to send 'Consumption Report' to 'Alias PII removed'.
MessageTaskRunner worker thread 25 10:06:30 WARN  Message sending error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.EDS.Core.Exceptions.InvalidMessageException: Failed to send the email message due to incorrect data.
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatTransportClient.SendAsync(Email message)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<RetryOnFault>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<SendTaskAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider.<SendEmailAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchProviderBase.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.SendEmail.SendEmail.Process(SendMessageArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.PipelineHelper.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Sitecore.EDS.Core.Exceptions.InvalidMessageException: Failed to send the email message due to incorrect data.
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatTransportClient.SendAsync(Email message)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<RetryOnFault>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.ChilkatMessageTransport.<SendTaskAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider.<SendEmailAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchProviderBase.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.EDS.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()<-
```

Stuffs I tried already are :

1) Contacts are getting created after rebuilding and swapping SOLR indexes.
2) Xconnect is working fine.

Also, EXM is re-attempting to send same mail again and again which has created huge queue in dispatchQueue of EXM. I already cleared the same once but issue still persist.